# how is local minima possible in gradient descent?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, neural-networks, artificial-intelligence, mean-square-error

gradient descent works on the equation of [mean squared error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_squared_error), which is an equation of a parabola `y=x^2`

we often say weight adjustment in a neural network by gradient descent algorithm can hit a local minima and get stuck in there.

My question is, how is local minima possible on the equation of a parabola, where the slope is always parabolic !

Comment: Has to be a coding error surely, there is only one local minimum on said parabola

Comment: The mean squared error is not simply the equation of a parabola $y=x^2$. If it was, there would be no need to use gradient descent, since the minimum is obviously at $x=0$. Look more carefully at what you are trying to minimize when you do weight adjustment.

Comment: @Rahul the equation of a parabola is y = (x + a) ^ 2 + b, substitute any value for 'a' and 'b' to shift the parabola along the axis.
the mean squared error is simply an equation of a parabola.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior is parabolic close to a minimum, but there can be as many minima as you want !

Think of a total least-squares line fitting problem where there are just four points forming a square. By symmetry, there must be several solutions (diagonals or medians), and there will be several local minima.